# 18.04 Ubuntu Budgie: How do I add a link to the Applications menu in plank?

Tags: budgie, plank

Just trying to simulate my workflow on my main laptop (running OSX) on my spare laptop.

Answer (score 4):

To add applications to Start Menu in Ubuntu / Lubuntu / Budgie, you have to create a Launcher in the **/usr/share/applications/** folder as follows:

`sudo gedit /usr/share/applications/<launcher_name>.desktop`

Then edit these entries accordingly. You can also copy additional entries from existing launcher in the Category where you want the launcher to appear.

```
[Desktop Entry]
Type=Application
Icon=<path to icon>
Name=<name to appear in menu>
Comment=<tooltip>       
Categories=<menu categories>
Exec=<path to executable>
Path=<set working directory if necessary>
StartupNotify=true
Terminal=false
```

**Add Launcher to the Dock in Budgie**: Drag&Drop the launcher from the Menu into the Dock.

Answer (score 2):

I created a lightweight deb installer to do this for Plank (and similar 3rd party docks), check out my repo here https://github.com/milan102/Ubuntu-Launchpad

The installation instructions are in the github README. The program is a simple shell script that invokes the keyboard shortcut for showing applications (Super + A)

Answer (score 0):

You might be able to do it with the **Gnome Extensions**: [Dash to Dock](https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/307/dash-to-dock/), [Dash to Panel](https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/1160/dash-to-panel/) or [Ubuntu Dock](https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/1300/ubuntu-dock/) along with the [Show Applications](https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/812/show-applications/), basically you should be looking into ***drag-and-dropping*** the Show Applications icon into the Plank Dock.

I don't use Plank, so I can't really tell if it will work, but you can give it a try. Also you might use **Gnome Tweak Tools** to further customize your experience.

Last, but not least, you might also get this working by using the [following code](https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=171354) in a standard icon launcher and later dragging it to the Plank:

```
dbus-send --session --type=method_call --dest=org.gnome.Shell /org/gnome/Shell org.gnome.Shell.Eval string:'Main.overview.show(); if (! Main.overview.viewSelector._showAppsButton.checked) {Main.overview.viewSelector._showAppsButton.checked = true;} else {Main.overview.hide();};'
```

If you run that in the terminal it will bring the "**Show Applications**" action view. Also you could just use the [keyboard shortcut](https://bugzilla.gnome.org/show_bug.cgi?id=685738): `Super + A`.

Hope this helps.

Comment: This answer is for GNOME shell. The OP is about Budgie.